# Complex T-SQL Substring

Tags: substring, sql-server-2008-r2

Just to be clear, I cannot use CLR UDF for this and `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` just don't cut the mustard.

We have a faux account management system with accounts being sub-accounts of others, better described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403602/cte-hierachy-descending-but-picking-up-child-nodes-not-parents-from-ancestor) (with tables too :) )

Now, assuming I have an account `2.4.1.3` (obviously, the parent becomes `2.4.1`) and if wanted to extract the 'prefix' `2.4.1` so that I may create another sibling account with the next ID in line (assume `2.4.1.4`) how would I go about splitting such a string in T-SQL?

Of course, a similar way can be applied to children accounts, but that's just butterscotch for this sundae.

Comment: Have you considered using the built in `HierarchyId` type? `select CAST('/2/4/1/3/' as HierarchyId).GetAncestor(1).ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @accountno VARCHAR(50) = '2.4.1.3'

SELECT 
   REVERSE(@accountno),
   CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@accountno)),
   SUBSTRING(@accountno, 1, LEN(@accountno) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@accountno)))
```

That third element in the `SELECT` statement should be the one that extracts the "prefix" `2.4.1` from your account number string.

Basically, what I do is reverse the string and then look for the first occurence of the dot (`'.'`) - the first in the reversed string is the last in the original string, and that's what you want to extract up to.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks mate, scratched my head on that one for 2 hours now and I wasn't willing to waste more time. Sure was easy for you :)